# What is the proper way to route dashboard components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm building a dashboard for my Vue app, and I have a question about how to handle the dashboard routing.

I have my dashboard container component that has the following structure:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <side-nav />
    <div>
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The goal is to have the different components render while keeping the nav and other content static.

I have the following structure in my routes:

```js
{
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/dashboard/home",
        component: AccountHome,
        alias: "/dashboard"
      },
      {
        path: "/dashboard/settings",
        component: Settings
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to know what the proper way is to set a default component to render inside of my dashboard. Right now I want the URL of the landing page when the user authenticates to be `/dashboard` and render a `AccountHome` component. The above route works using an alias, but doesn't seem like the right way to solve the problem.

If I don't have the alias, there is no component in the `router-view`, so I end up just rendering the static dashboard components.

Is there a different way that I could handle this? Or a standard for handling dashboard routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your header, footer and other fixed layout elements would go in a layout file or directly in App.vue as Vue *components*. The layout would envelope your dynamic views and uses a router-view slot to achieve this.

Something like this is typical:

```html
    <template>
      <TheHeader/>
      <ErrorMessage/>
      
      <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <transition>
          <component :is="Component"></component>
        </transition>
      </router-view>

      <TheFooter />
    </template>
```

It seems like you have chosen to render an empty Dashboard component and want its first child to show the Dashboard content. This is a good approach, add a DashboardHome component and hook it up like this in the router in order to show it while keeping /dashboard as your root route:

```
  children: [
    // DashboardHome will be rendered inside Dashboard's <router-view>
    { path: '', component: DashboardHome }
]
```

I don't use children for most of my dashboard views because I don't see the need for /dashboard/* in my URLs, it's not semantically interesting like it would be for /settings/organization/ or /user/new etc. This means I have my dashboard routes at the outermost hierarchical level of router.js, so each item is a sibling of /dashboard and not a child.

I do use child routes for simpler/smaller content bits, like /signup/success. Here I show the children with v-if instead of a separate template, like this:

```html
    <div class="container" v-if="signupStatus.signedUp && !signupStatus.signingUp">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
```

If you want to keep /dashboard in your URL and nest the route views with proper templates, you can nest as many new router-views or router-view slots as you wish below your Dashboard route level (nest as deep as you wish). Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! It was really helpful for me. I have one follow up question based on the code you included. Is it common to use a `transition` tag inside of a `router-view` like you have above? I've never seen that before but I think it's interesting.

Comment: Yes, I think it's pretty common for components, the transition could wrap the components closely or even be inside of the component itself. I found out after experimenting that transitions worked better and smoother when they were closely attached to the items to actually transition, as opposed to wrapping the whole view. Having it inside of the view also allows for use of different, named transitions depending on the page or elements to animate or fade.